# changing jquery ui dialogue title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cdG94/2/ in which I am trying to change the jquery UI dialogue title..It works fine when I am using Jquery 1.9 or lower but when I go to higher library it just displays the HTML directly ..am I doing something wrong here .I am using Jquery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI - v1.10.3

```
<button id="opener">Open the dialog</button>
<div id="wrapper">
<p>Some txt goes here</p>
</div>

$('#wrapper').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    minHeight: 400,
    minWidth: 600,
    title: function () {
                   return "Testing&nbsp<span style=\"font-size:smaller;\">Testing the HTML .</span>";
               }
});
$('#opener').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#changed-title-option-from-html-to-text  in jquery 1.10, the title is now Text only.  You'd have to override the _title() method of the dialog to set HTML.  Also, I'm surprised it accepts a function, I've never tried that.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein thanks for the link - if you don't mind I'll reference it in my answer

Comment: @ScottMermelstein also, looking at the source, the "accept a function" doesn't appear to be documented, but is a side effect of passing the given option directly to `.text`, which _does_ accept a function.

Comment: @alnitak Neat side effect, thanks for actually diving into the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery UI 1.10 they changed the `title` option so that it uses `.text()` instead of `.html()` to set the dialog's title:

From the jQuery UI 1.10 [release notes](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#changed-title-option-from-html-to-text):

> **Changed title option from HTML to text**
>
> ([#6016](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6016)) Dialog titles are controlled either via the `title` option or the `title` attribute on the content element. The title has previously been set as HTML, but since titles are generally plain text, this could easily cause a scripting vulnerability for users who don't realize the value is being set as HTML. As a result, titles are now set as text. If you need to add custom formatting to your dialog titles, you can override the `_title()` method on the dialog.

To revert to the original behaviour you can therefore do this, *per the jQuery UI team's recommendation*:

```
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.extend({}, $.ui.dialog.prototype, {
    _title: function (title) {
        if (!this.options.title) {
            title.html("&#160;");
        }
        title.html(this.options.title);
    }
}));
```

but do beware (if you allow user supplied input to appear in the titles) of the potential for XSS vulnerabilities that was the original reason for the change!

(demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/bJ47w/)

Comment: Among other things, this is a global fix in that it will make `title` work the way its expected in *all* dialogs, while the other answer is specific only to whatever dialog it is added.  Also, this answer doesn't require any DOM parsing at all, and most directly fixes the problem.  (Both are solutions to the problem, though.)

Answer (score 3):

As far as `title` option changed from html to text, you can adjust small hack to face html content in jQuery UI dialog window title.

**This is not best practice**, but maybe a solution sometimes. Here is an example:

*Trigger a function, when dialog is created and manually change title .html*

```
$('#wrapper').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    minHeight: 400,
    minWidth: 600,
    create: function () {
        $('#wrapper').prev().html($('#wrapper').prev().text());
    },
    title: function () {
        return "Testing&nbsp<span style=\"font-size:smaller;\">Testing the HTML .</span>";
    }
});
$('#opener').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/cdG94/8/

Comment: this code will not work reliably with the hard-coded ID in it.

Comment: Two suggestions for improvements: rather than use `ui-id-1`, maybe use `$('#wrapper').prev()` - that seems a little bit less hardcoded.  Also, the create function could be `$('#ui-id-1').html($('#ui-id-1').text())` (or use `$('#wrapper').prev()`, of course) so it only needs to be set once.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein totally agree with you. Just updated my answer. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein actually I'd go for `$(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-title')`

Comment: @Alnitak yep it can be played with many variation to get optimal way, but main idea was to find an alternative way to get HTML title. I don't say that you are wrong, I just mean that this is only matter of playing with DOM

Comment: I actually like @Alnitak's answer better, in that it should always work, while mine is based on the assumption that the title will always be placed above the div.  I always forget about using `closest`.

Comment: @Alnitak instead of `.ui-dialog-title` now you have `.ui-dialog-titlebar` everything is changing in this world ;)

Comment: @zur4ik the `.ui-dialog-titlebar` is for the whole bar - `.ui-dialog-title` is just the label.  (I do have _extensive_ experience modifying both!)

Comment: @zur4ik also, the main point of using `$(this)...` in that example is to avoid repeating the original dialog's selector - "don't repeat yourself", hence making that `create` option usable on _any_ dialog, not just `#wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, the newer version of JQuery UI doesn't use HTML.

However, it looks like you are just trying to make the text smaller. Why not do this using CSS:

```
.ui-dialog-title{
    font-size: smaller !important;
}
```

Comment: I m trying to make a part of text smaller